# Debug problems in IntelliJ 2016.2 with grails 2.4.3

Tags: debugging, grails, intellij-idea

I have problems with debugging in IntelliJ Idea 2016.2.
I am using grails version 2.4.3

But sometimes the debugger works not as excpected. The debugger does not stop on breakpoints even if the code is executed. Sometimes the debugger shows me, that he is in wrong branch of an if statement, but the code is not executed. The debugger also sometimes stops in catch blocks, but no exception is thrown and so on and so on.

Does anybody face the same problems? Is this a problem with IntelliJ? Are there any other tools which I could use?

Comment: I used to have similar problems but with eclipse. Did you try classic restart of IDE / reimporting project / restart of machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar problem. Downgrading to version 2016.1 seems to solve it. Think that we should wait for some newer version of Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with grails and Intellij when I use autoreloading.

Intellij not recognize the 'new' code to debug and stop on breakpoint at the 'old' point.

Stop and re-run your application probably solve that.

Comment: My problems often occures, even after reloading the application. Still the problems exists

Comment: Is it an option to use some sort of remote debugger?

Comment: You are using remote debug?
You are going to have to be sure that you are working from the exact source that was used to build the classes you are debugging.

Comment: No, I am not using a remote debugger, I want to know if it is a better option